# When my game in unity starts, my character collides with objects it isn't touching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, game-development

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _Pickaxe;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
     _Pickaxe = GameObject.Find("Pickaxe");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
     
    void Update()
    {
   
   
    }
    void DestroyGameObject()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    
    

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Collided with +" + collision.gameObject.name);
            if(collision.gameObject.name == "Pickaxe" );
        {
        Debug.Log("Touched pick");  
        }
       
    }
}
```

In my script it logs whatever the character touches. In my scene i have a object placed about 10m away from where the player capsule spawns, somehow it collides with it before you can even move.

Comment: Is there a chance you spawn everything at Vector3.zero and then after spawning move the object to somewhere else? Without showing the scene setup, collider sizes and so on it is hard to help you. Also better avoid GameObject.Find and assign the correct object in the inspector. If you have 2 GameObjects with the same name it won't work as expected. Same goes for the 'collision.gameObject.name =='. Better create a Tag and put it on the Pickaxe and use 'collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickaxe")

Answer (score 1):

Your code have an error. It logs `"Touched pick"` for every collision. To fix it, your should remove the semicolon in this line `if(collision.gameObject.name == "Pickaxe" );`

Comment: Worked a treat thanks!

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)